# mini-batch gradient descent implementation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient-descent

When reading an tensorflow implementation for a deep learning model, I am trying to understand the following code segment included in the training process.

```
self.net.gradients_node = tf.gradients(loss, self.variables)
for epoch in range(epochs):
            total_loss = 0
            for step in range((epoch*training_iters), ((epoch+1)*training_iters)):
                batch_x, batch_y = data_provider(self.batch_size)

                # Run optimization op (backprop)
                _, loss, lr, gradients = sess.run((self.optimizer, self.net.cost, self.learning_rate_node, self.net.gradients_node), 
                                                  feed_dict={self.net.x: batch_x,
                                                             self.net.y: util.crop_to_shape(batch_y, pred_shape),
                                                             self.net.keep_prob: dropout})

                if avg_gradients is None:
                    avg_gradients = [np.zeros_like(gradient) for gradient in gradients]
                for i in range(len(gradients)):
                    avg_gradients[i] = (avg_gradients[i] * (1.0 - (1.0 / (step+1)))) + (gradients[i] / (step+1))

                norm_gradients = [np.linalg.norm(gradient) for gradient in avg_gradients]
                self.norm_gradients_node.assign(norm_gradients).eval()



                total_loss += loss
```

I think it is related to mini-batch gradient descent, but I cannot understand how does it work, or I have some difficulties to connect it to the algorithm shown as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to mini batch SGD.

It computes average gradient over all timesteps. After the first timestep `avg_gradients` will contain the gradient that was just computed, after the second step it will be elementwise mean of the two gradients from the two steps, after `n` steps it will be elementwise mean of all the `n` gradients computed so far. These mean gradients are then normalized (so that their norm is one). It is hard to tell why those average gradients are needed without the context in which they were presented.

Comment: Hi lshamael, thank you for the reply. I include the whole training iteration part in the original post. The other thing that confuses me is about avg_gradients, which was originally defined as zero. Then in avg_gradients[i] = (avg_gradients[i] * (1.0 - (1.0 / (step+1)))) + (gradients[i] / (step+1)), since avg_gradients[i] =0, looks like the first term in the left side just equals to 0. and avg_gradients[i] = gradients[i]/(step+1), is that right? I just cannot figure out what does this gradient opeartion aims to achieve.

Comment: Yes, it is right **on the first step**, at which time `step+1` = 1, and so `avg_gradients[i] = grandients[i]`. On each consecutive step the condition `avg_gradients is None` doesn't hold, and so it is no longer zero.

Comment: I see, thanks. But what's the underlying algorithm(or logic) for this implementation, if it is not batch SGD. I just updated the original post.

Comment: The actual minibatch SGD happens in the lines `batch_x, batch_y = data_provider(self.batch_size)` (this gives you a minibatch of data) and `sess.run((self.optimizer` (this performs the actual SGD, or, more likely, some advanced version of it such as Adam or RMSProp, depending on what `optimizer` is). It is still unclear why they need these averaged gradients, they don't use them anywhere